# ElasticSearch sort on multiple fields with summation

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am doing a search using "filtered" query and then want to sort on SUM of 3 columns.

Eg:

```
"query": {
    ...
},
"sort": {
    view_count + comment_count + like_count
    order: DESC
}
```

The result should be in descending order of the sum of the above 3 counts.

How to achieve the SUM the columns and then order the results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: a "brute force" method would be to add a sum_count field to a document and update it every time you update any of three components

Answer (score 3):

Use [script sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) if you can't change the data/don't have control over the mapping/the three fields are changing (ie they are not insert and forget).

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": "return doc['view_count'].value + doc['comment_count'].value + doc['like_count'].value,
      "lang": "groovy",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

If you update the documents frequently, you can also add another field - let's call it `sum` - where you already index the sum of the three fields. And then you simply sort on the `sum` field.

Comment: It worked with "groovy" but as it is disabled by default, had to enabled it first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Elasticsearch 5.6), below code sorts by sum  of multiple fields.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query" : {
      "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
  },
"sort" : {
  "_script" : {
      "type" : "number",
      "script" : {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['retweet_count'].value + doc['favorite_count'].value"
      },
      "order" : "desc"
  }
}}
```

Source: [Script-based Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting)